# Failing to store bitmap as a file

Tags: android

Im trying to save a bitmap as a file however its failing for some reason

Thats the error I keep getting, it only pops up on 5.0 however I tested it on 6.0 sdk and its working fine
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/Pictures/mFile/image1491238127.jpg: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

```
private File saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String path) {


    File file = null;
    if (bitmap != null) {
        file = new File(path);
        file.mkdirs();
        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
            try {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);

                // bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        return Compressor.getDefault(getContext()).compressToFile(file);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return file;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private  File saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();

    String fname = "Image-Fashom" +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I observe on your code I found you creating file.mkdir(); it means you creating a new file not get u need to write the code after try catch return exception.

```
try {
  //it gets file path
  file = new File(path);  
  return Compressor.getDefault(getContext()).compressToFile(file);
}catch (Exception e){
     return file;
 }
```

ting the exist file..

Comment: file.mkdir() was just to check the flag of file creating, after it was crashing, I forgot to take it off

Comment: `i found u creating file.mkdir(); it means u creating a new file `. No. A new directory. That's the problem.

Comment: `I forgot to take it off`. That is ok. But you have to do something more otherwise you keep the error message.